# Perl Split using "*"

Tags: regex, string, perl, split

If I use `split` like this:

```
my @split = split(/\s*/, $line);
print "$split[1]\n";
```

with `input`:

`cat   dog`

I get:

`a`

However if I use `\s+` in `split`, I get:

`dog`

I'm curious as to why they don't produce the same result? Also, what is the proper way to split a string by character?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\s*` effectively means zero or more whitespace characters. Between `c` and `a` in `cat` are zero spaces, yielding the result you're seeing.

To the regex engine, your string looks as follows:

```
c
    zero spaces
a
    zero spaces
t
    multiple spaces
d
    zero spaces
o
    zero spaces
g
```

Following this logic, if you use `\s+` as a separator, it will only match the multiple spaces between `cat` and `dog`.

Answer (score 3):

`*` matches 0 or more times. Which means it can match the empty string between characters. `+` matches 1 or more times, which means it must match at least one character.

This is described in the documentation for [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

> If PATTERN matches the empty string, the EXPR is split at the match position (between characters).

Additionally, when you split on whitespace, most of the time you really want to use a literal space:

```
.. split ' ', $line;
```

As described here:

> As another special case, "split" emulates the default behavior of the
>   command line tool awk when the PATTERN is either omitted or a *literal
>   string* composed of a single space character (such as ' ' or "\x20",
>   but not e.g. "/ /"). In this case, any leading whitespace in EXPR is
>   removed before splitting occurs, and the PATTERN is instead treated as
>   if it were "/\s+/"; in particular, this means that *any* contiguous
>   whitespace (not just a single space character) is used as a separator.
>   However, this special treatment can be avoided by specifying the
>   pattern "/ /" instead of the string " ", thereby allowing only a
>   single space character to be a separator.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to split a string into a list of individual characters then you should use an empty regex pattern for `split`, like this

```
my $line = 'cat';
my @split = split //, $line;
print "$_\n" for @split;
```

**output**

```
c
a
t
```

Some people prefer `unpack`, like this

```
my @split = unpack '(A1)*', $line;
```

which gives exactly the same result.